# Access the same file from different backgroundworker instances

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I need some little assistance!
Ive spent several days looking for a solution, so far seems that no one has encountered this wall.

Ive created a file transfer that moves files from a specified server to other PCs within the network, this app is user by 5 people, and the issue I am facing here is that if one person is accessing this file and it is being copied, all other 4 programs get rendered useless until that transfer is completed, this said, no error is displayed and the 4 programs (running on different machines) go directly to the "RunWorkerCompleted" procedure and thats it, I get it that the file is being used and therefore is locked, but is there a way to force the backgroundworker not to lock the file?

here is the entire code used on my project:

```
Private w101 As String
Private SaveDir As String

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim parts As String() = w101.Split(New Char() {"\"c})
    Dim filename As String = parts(parts.Count - 1)
    Dim streamRead As New System.IO.FileStream(w101, System.IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, IO.FileShare.Read)
    Dim streamWrite As New System.IO.FileStream(SaveDir + "\" + filename, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, IO.FileShare.None)
    Dim lngLen As Long = streamRead.Length - 1
    Dim lnglenres As Long = lngLen / 1048576
    Dim byteBuffer(4096) As Byte
    Dim intBytesRead As Integer
    setLabelTxt1("STATUS : (0/" + (lnglenres * 1).ToString + " MB) Transferred.", KITTASK_media1progress)
    Try
        While (streamWrite.Length < streamRead.Length)
            If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit While
            End If
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CLng(streamRead.Position / lngLen * 100))
            setLabelTxt1("STATUS : (" + CLng(streamRead.Position / 1048576).ToString + " MB / " + (lnglenres * 1).ToString + " MB) Transferred.", KITTASK_media1progress)
            intBytesRead = (streamRead.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 4096))
            streamWrite.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intBytesRead)
        End While
        streamWrite.Flush()
        streamWrite.Close()
        streamRead.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    On Error Resume Next
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    On Error Resume Next
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        MsgBox("File transfer cancelled by user.")
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        KITTASK_media1progress.Text = "STATUS : Ready"
    Else
        MsgBox("1 ok")
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        KITTASK_media1progress.Text = "STATUS : Ready"
    End If
End Sub
```

any help is greatly appreciated! thank you for taking the time to read this post.

Comment: I believe those streams need to be in `Using` blocks so `Dispose` is called. Won't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `IO.FileAccess.Read` instead of `ReadWrite`?

Comment: Simplify your life; use System.IO.File.Copy

Comment: @AndrewMorton yep, it was actually Read only first, I thought that maybe readwrite would to the trick as for the permissions, but it seems it is a windows thing that locks the file while being in use.

I tried to implement the suggestion from CaiusJard and just could not make it work correctly.

I ended using a different approach, making a pool of 10 files and sequentially verifying if they are in use, if in use check the next, until it finds one that is not being in use and transfer that file as the source.